# JBoss: 32 vs 64 Bit Performance differences?

Tags: linux, performance, jboss, ejb

I know that it is a pretty vague question but I was hoping to get some ideas about where to look as it is a little puzzling to me.

I have a web app that computes some value and returns it to the client (EJB remote calls).  When I call my localhost from a main() test looping 10 times, it comes back within about 100 milliseconds.  When I call the DEV machine following the same process, it is sometimes fast and sometimes really slow, like 4 seconds, which is a huge difference.

The weird thing is that my localhost is a 32 bit 1GB Jboss config but my DEV machine is a 64 bit 6GB Jboss config so if anything, I would expect my localhost to hang... not the the DEV machine.

Where would you suggest starting the troubleshooting process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved the issue after finding out that the install on the linux machine actually had two different instances of JBoss running on the VM therefore resulting in unpredictable behavior. The resources that were consumed were enormous, which did not make any sense based on the app that was deployed...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, both calls are made from same computer? If that is the case, network between is much more likely source for response time differences than 32 vs. 64 bit.

If that is not the case, then monitor dev and check what is the difference in context (other applications etc.) between "fast" and "4 seconds" cases. Anyway, most likely difference in response times have nothing to with difference between 32 bit / 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, both calls are made from the same computer.  I also had some doubts about the network...  There is no difference in context in the sense that both machines only have my app deployed to it.  The only difference is that DEV is on a linux machine and my localhost is on Windows XP.

Comment: Well, I should add that DEV was a new machine "created" for me in the sense that is a linux virtual machine.

Comment: then also consider checking what other virtual machines you have on the same DEV hardware, may be it's having hard time balancing resources between your VM and others.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I worked on application which was deployed on JBoss on two servers with exactly the same hardware configuration. The first server had CentOS and the second FreeBSD. Exactly the same hardware, the same network, similar load. From what I observed, application responses when it was running on FreeBSD was about 1.5 - 2 times faster. On the first sight, it was strange for me, but after week of tests differences in response times was confirmed.

Since that time I do not consider hardware configuration as so important as I thought before ;)